# Why does the T-1000 react differently to different impacts?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

When the T-800 hits the T-1000 towards the end, it is in a solid form until Arnold's fist goes through its head, where it can willingly turn into liquid and regroup itself to battle Arnold into the gear.

If it goes into shock every time it is hit with a bullet, how does it withstand that blow? Smaller bullets seem to form craters and knock it back, yet a big slug goes through it and it is seen literally walking up to Sarah Connor unphased?

Comment: “Based of the previous question (Question About the Composition of the T-1000 Terminator Judgement Day)” — Do you have a URL for that question? That would be more helpful.

Comment: I do have the URL; however, that question was edited so much from what it was; it actually does not make sense in reference to this question.

Comment: I also don't think big slugs go through the T-1000.  They just seem to burrow themselves in a lot deeper than smaller rounds.  I never got the impression that any rounds were going clear through his body.

Answer (score 10):

At this stage of the fight the T-1000 has suffered a bit of damage.

- It's been exposed to an entire Tanker full of Liquid Nitrogen (and subsequently shot into tiny pieces whilst frozen).
- It was then rapidly heated from sub-zero temperatures due to the nearby molten steel in the steel mill.

Not to mention the multitude of bullets and other debris that it's had to deal with over the course of the movie.

We're shown examples of how it is losing it's ability to hold itself together. In the extended cuts, It puts it's hand on a yellow/black "warning" handrail, and it's hand deforms around the metal and matches it's pattern. Later on, we see that with each step, it's feet melt slightly into the floor. Needless to say, it's not doing so well by this point.

**So what does this have to do with the T-800 punching through it's head?**

Most of the fight in the mill between the T-1000 and the T-800 is a grapple fight. Grab->Throw->Repeat. The T-1000s body could handle that fairly well and maintain it's cohesiveness.

I believe that - under prime-fighting conditions - the T-800 wouldn't have been able to punch straight through the T-1000's head. **However**, due to the damage it is suffering, **the T-1000's body is losing the ability to hold itself together.**

I don't think the T-1000 did that move willingly. I think the T-800 punched hard enough to break through the failing liquid-metal, and the T-1000 *compensated* by regrowing it's head and turning it's head into it's hands. *And this wasn't the only instance of this happening* - later, the T-800 finds a large steel bar and swings it straight down through the T-1000, nearly slicing it in two.

In conclusion, I don't think it was **deliberately** reacting differently to hits, but **compensating** from it's own current weakness. Both the punch and the steel bar were solid blows, enough to break through the failing liquid-metal. It is clearly suffering from the effects of it's freezing/thawing, and this is noticeable even in fight sequences.

Comment: Even as we see that it breaks down, I sincerely think that that is how the way a T-1000 behaves. Remember, when the T-1000 was shot in the elevator scene, it was blown apart. That is just how the poly mimetic metal reacts. I am just wondering why the T-1000 was able to react so quickly, when it is usually put into shock with any kind of blow, be it a shotgun bullet and/or a metal fist.

Comment: This also fails to explain how the T-1000 was able to react to being thrown against a wall by instantly reversing his body (his front side immediately appears where his back side had been when he hit the wall).  This doesn't strike me as a sign that T-1000 is suffering from the cumulative effects of the damage done to him up to that point.  It suggests that he is functioning at a near-optimal level.  I doubt that he didn't mean for the fist to go through his head.  He was simply exploiting his advantage over the T-800.

Comment: @Wad & Arvin - the shotgun to the face has a higher impact velocity, and the wall was not nearly as much directed force as the punch. We're also shown throughout the movie that the T-1000 is smarter & faster than the 800, thus it's ability to quickly react in intense situations is still very high. It's still reacting and compensating for the T-800s tactics in those scenarios

Comment: @Robotnik - I agree with most of that.  But allowing the fist to pass harmlessly through his head and then grabbing the T-800's arm while he is off balance is just a brilliant move - I see no reason to suspect that it was anything other than deliberate on the T-1000's part.  If he didn't mean to do it, it was the most fortuitous accident that ever happened. If I could turn my head to liquid and reform it into hands, I never would have lost a fight in my life.  I can't do that, though, which is why my eye socket was fractured in 2 places.

Comment: @Wad - Lol ouch. But also the thing to remember is that the T-1000 is, above all else, a very powerful computer. It's body may be failing but it's still capable of reacting faster than any human, to the point that anyone watching that fight (I.e. us) it looks like a planned move. The T-800 never had anywhere near that level of reaction speed, mainly because it was built as a frontal assault unit - get close enough that they can see and suspect you for being a terminator, and whilst they're thinking about it, mow them down with guns. (Cont.)

Comment: Whereas the T-1000 was built for infiltration: able to blend in better (see how it interacts with John's foster parents), take on any shape, and effectively think on its feet. It also seems to specialise for melee combat with the ability to create knives etc.

Comment: Again, if it wasn't planned, it was the luckiest accident that ever happened to anyone, ever.  And if he is capable of reacting so quickly, why does he stand there with an "Oh, shit!" look on his face for at least 3 seconds between the grenade round hitting him and the grenade blowing up?  If he was capable of superhuman speed, he should have turned himself into a puddle of metal.  It would have given him a far better chance of survival.

Comment: Being able to think fast doesn't mean he can react fast. Otherwise, why doesn't he go all Matrix-y and dodge bullets?

Comment: I don't know about you, but I can imagine a human doing what T-1000 does here, more or less.  A skilled martial artist could see a punch coming at his face, dodge it, grab his opponent's fist while he is off balance from missing the target, then pull the opponent further off balance and launch a counterattack.  It would be planned, in a way, but it would happen so fast that it was more instinct than conscious thought.  But no martial artist can dodge a bullet before it hits him.

Comment: @Wad - Sure, but a martial artist that sees the punch coming is different from one that doesn't. The T-1000 got caught off guard for a split second when the 800 threw that punch. Perhaps the fact that the 800 had been 'learning', and it throwing a punch wasn't what the T-1000 was expecting? We could argue this all day lol, but truth is there isn't definitive evidence either way. I personally put it down to the malleability of the liquid metal at that time, you give the T-1000s ability to predict more weight.

Comment: And you literally said the T-1000 is "capable of reacting faster than any human".  Now you say "Being able to think fast doesn't mean he can react fast"?  Which is it?  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: Dodging a bullet is beyond human capabilities.  Dodging a punch is not. I don't know how you can be sure he was caught off guard before the punch.  Who knows how he even detects motion?  Just through his eyes?  I doubt it.  I'm guessing he is almost impossible to catch off guard.

Comment: @Wad - what I meant was that it can *think* fast - As soon as the punch was through it's head, it started reacting. Doesn't mean it's fast enough to react and dodge bullets (if it even cared that it was taking them). And yeah, it sees through it's eyes, countless moments in the movie we're shown it searching using it's eyes - The encounter with John in the arcade for example.

Comment: So it is blind in it's liquid form?  Nonsense.  It was trying to appear human, so it did what humans do - we look with our eyes.  But it lacks the anatomical features involved in human eyesight.  Its eyes CAN'T work like ours.

Comment: The blobs of metal couldn't have seen things visually, but they knew which way to move so they could reassemble themselves.  They must have other sensory abilities.

Comment: Of course it probably has different senses, this doesn't mean that it doesn't use its eyes when it has them. It turns it's head when the kid points to John, *sees* him, and starts pursuit. It flicks them up to check the mirror in Pescadero State Hospital when the orderly isn't looking. It turns it's head when it hears the chopper at Cyberdyne (before it drives out the window). It uses it's eyes *all the time*.

Comment: @Robotnik - I forgot about the scenes where he "looks" when he isn't around anyone else.  That definitely proves your point.  It doesn't make sense, since his eyes can't contain clear fluid like ours do, which should mean they don't work at all, but I suppose we shouldn't look for logic in a movie about time traveling kill bots sent to assassinate the chosen one.  There are bigger problems with Terminator movie logic - like why Skynet didn't send an army of assassins to ancient Africa and wipe out all the ancestors of humans before they were able to defend themselves effectively.

Comment: @Robotnik - but that doesn't necessarily mean I was wrong about the T-1000 being able to sense the punch coming - his eyes obviously work somehow, but he still might be able to anticipate an impending punch with his other senses, like motion detectors or something.

Comment: @WadCheber - Maybe, but still we will never know for sure :). It's open to interpretation. I just reckon they needed Arnie to get a lucky punch in for the T-1000 to compensate and turn in it's favour. :)

Answer (score 1):

Fighting effectively isn't just learning how to efficiently damage your opponent.  You must also learn how to absorb punishment and keep functioning.  The T-1000 started the film with a very limited ability to cope with unplanned deformations of its body.  Over the course of the movie as the T-1000 experienced more violent impacts it developed better algorithms that allowed it to restore functionality more quickly.  By the end of the film it was mostly unfazed by gun fire, merely jolted by the impacts.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it has to do with kinetics. Energy imparted on target by any missile (and bullet is missile) depends on speed of said missile and it's mass. Bullet, despite having low mass, has great velocity, which causes T-100 to reel back from impact (how much? that's another answer). However, T-800 fist is a somewhat different missile. It would be a piledriver of sorts, actually, with much greater energy due to the speed of the fist (low, of course, compared to bullet) but with greater mass (which, in this instance, would be T-800 body). This much force can, apparently, break the cohesion of the molecules comprising T-1000.

Or can it? Maybe the right question here is Tactics?

I'd say that it "willingly turn into liquid and regroup itself to battle Arnold into the gear" and that had much less to do with being hit, but rather gaining advantage over T-800. And it apparently worked.

Also, from what I know the "wounds" from Sarah's shoutgun would be more than likely with solid shot (not "buckshot" - and this is intended simplification) - biiig bullet, average velocity... but it's still just a bullet. Compare that to 40mm later...

Comment: The "wounds" caused by Sarah's shotgun suggest that she was firing solid slugs, not buckshot.

Comment: Your answer seems to hold some validity. But why not allow small bullets to go through it? I am guessing, if it can really "choose" what goes through it and what it can deflect, the mechanisms within it would rather have something big go through and damage when it is solid.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar reacting to a punch before it hits you is easier than reacting to a bullet before it hits you.  He isn't *that* fast.

Comment: My understanding of concept of "mimetic poly-alloy" would be that there's no need for allowing bullets through - they don't harm him anyway. slow down? Maybe. Harm? No. Maybe except tank round. Man shot at doesn't die from wound per se - it's the hydrostatic shock that does most damage. This depends on the diameter of the bullet - FMJ is less lethal than HP precisely because of that and because doesn't tumble inside much, if at all. What in the bullet will kill T-1000? And @WadCheber is right - he's not fast enough to react to being hit. But doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I wouldn't say that he was "unphased" by Sarah's shotgun rounds - he recoils, halts for a second, then continues his slow advance towards her.  This is not consistent with his much more dramatic response to the 9mm rounds fired by the T-800 earlier in the movie.  We can only speculate about why he reacts so differently, and why a much larger round causes less of a reaction than a much smaller round.

As for the question of why the T-800's fist went straight through the T-1000's head, I have always assumed it did so because the T-1000 *wanted* it to.  He turned a strong attack against him to his advantage by using it as a chance to grab his opponent's hand, spin him around, and launch a counterattack.  It was a brilliant maneuver, and it worked out better than he had probably anticipated.

The suggestion that he was malfunctioning by this point doesn't hold up, in my opinion.  Just before the head-punch, he is thrown against a wall, and instantly liquifies, then reforms with his body pointed the opposite way (he hit the wall face first, and a second later his back is to the wall and he is facing the T-800 again.  I think he had suffered some degree of cumulative damage (after he is frozen, shattered, and reassembled, we see a ripple course upwards through his body, which I interpret as some sort of glitch), but not enough to significantly impair his functionality.

Yes, he is knocked back by bullets, but we never see him being shot while he is in his liquid form.  I suspect that shooting T-1000 while he was liquid would be useless and the bullets would pass right through him.  We don't know, however, because every time we see him being shot, he is in solid form.

The short answer is basically as follows: As a previous answer points out, a giant robot fist imparts far more force than a measly little bullet.  T-1000 didn't want to endure that amount of force if he could avoid it, and he wanted to gain the initiative in the fight, so he very cleverly allowed the fist to pass through his head without doing any damage, then exploited the fact that the T-800 was now off balance by grabbing his arm and whirling him around.  It was simply what the T-1000 chose to do, and it worked out very well for him.  He regained the upper hand, and temporarily incapacitated his opponent as a result.  He is just a very skilled combatant.

Comment: That is actually not a bad answer at all. I do wonder if the  self-awareness of the poly mimetic can choose what to let through and not. Then I would ask, why do the small bullets cause craters instead of going through while bigger bullets do that? Can it somehow anticipate the damage each can cause and so lets the small bullets hit it and the bigger bullets go through so they do not shatter his overall solid form? Like the metal can self-liquefy at will. Interesting.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - he may be faster than a human, but not by much.  It is tricky to anticipate and dodge a punch coming at you, but it is possible.  No one can move fast enough to dodge a bullet.  He probably doesn't have enough time to react to being shot at and liquefy his body before the bullet hits him.  It just happens too fast.

Comment: And I don't remember ever seeing a bullet pass clean through him.  Some just penetrate deeper than others.

Comment: If he could react that quickly, we might expect him to respond to the grenade round entering his torso by liquefying himself before it explodes.  I don't know what a 40mm grenade round would do to a puddle of liquid metal, but it would definitely do less damage than it did to the T-1000 in his solid form.

Comment: Well there was one that did. I mean we did not actually see a side angle of it; but towards the end, when Sarah shoots the T-1000, it goes straight through. This was the scene right before the T-800 splices him with the rod, that the T-800 later gets stabbed with.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - Right, I forgot about that- I vaguely recall a scene where he gets shot in the face and we see the hole in his head from behind...  Is that the shot you are talking about?